# Current user is not refreshing

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have created a user **Profile** in the **Drawer**. Where I used **SteamBuilder** to get the data like **usernaem** and **email** which saved in my firestore during my user authentication. when I first login It gets the value from firestore and show the **name** under the **CircleAvatar**. but when I ** log out** and ** sing** with **other users** but the **previous user ** information is not changed. Like in my **screenshot** there is a name **Md. Fazle Rabbi** its show even if I **log out** and **login** with another user but the name is not updated for the new user its remain the same.

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class UserDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  UserDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserDrawerState createState() => _UserDrawerState();
}

class _UserDrawerState extends State<UserDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          body: StreamBuilder(
              stream:
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext contex,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('User is not found');
                }
                return Stack(
                  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                    (document) {
                      return Stack(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 400),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80))),
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {}, child: Text('data'))),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 08,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {}, child: Text('data'))),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 105),
                            height: 300,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(120))),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 40,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  document['username'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 20),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                            height: 100,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            child: Text(
                              'Profile',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80))),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: In this screenshot my Drawer is showing a name. If I log out and log in with another user its not update the current user name]

Comment: Can you include your `logout` method?

Comment: I did into another file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code streams **all users** from `users` collection and displays all of them in a `Stack`. As a result you you will always see the last one read from the stream, on the top of your `Stack`. To achieve what you want you have to stream **only the current, logged in user**:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_uid).snapshots(),
```

`_uid` can be found like `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`, I assume you use `uid` given by Firebase Authentication. But you have to manage case when it is null.

You have to update you stream whenever a user is logged in or out. To do so you can listen to authentication state change with `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user)` and update `_uid` in the above stream.